# Datos de tabla en HTML no se separan bien

Tags: html, jquery, array, json

estaba trabajando con una tabla en HTML y me ha surgido la siguiente duda: estoy cogiendo los datos de un array JSON: `{"key":["1","2","3"],"values":["4","5","6"]}` y al intentar insertarlos en la tabla en vez de ponerse cada dato en una columna todos los datos se ponen en la primera columna, el código JS que estoy usando para insertar los datos en la tabla es el siguiente:

```
var idtabla = document.getElementById("idtabla")
  idtabla.innerHTML += window.location.href.split("/tabla/")[1]
  function getJson(){
    var id = window.location.href.split("/tabla/")[1]
    var table = document.getElementById("table")
    $.get( `/json`, (data) => {
      if(data.error){
        idtabla.innerHTML = 404 + ", tabla no encontrada"
      } else {
        var keys = data.key.forEach(element => {
            table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${element}</td>`
        });
        var values = data.values.forEach(element => {
table.innerHTML += `<td>${element}</td></tr>`
        });
      }
      
    })
  
  }
```

y el resultado que me da es este: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podría solucionarse?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba cambiando esto:

```javascript
var keys = data.key.forEach(element => {
            table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${element}</td>`
        });
var values = data.values.forEach(element => {
            table.innerHTML += `<td>${element}</td></tr>`
        });
```

por esto:

```javascript
data.key.forEach( (element, index) => {
  table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${element}</td><td>${data.values[index]}</td></tr>`
});
```

### Explicación:

(He quitado el `var keys =` porque no le veo sentido.)

Agregamos el parámetro **index** en la [función de fecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#sintaxis_b%C3%A1sica) para conseguir, en cada ciclo del bucle **forEach**, el índice de cada **key**, y presuponiendo que los números de índice de **data.key** y de **data.values** siempre van a ser correspondientes entre si, lo usamos para encontrar el valor correspondiente al mismo indice de **data.values** del ciclo actual mediante `data.values[index]`.  Y lo ponemos todo junto en un solo innerHTML.

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias por la respuesta!